# Connecting to an existing database from a laravel project

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I want to use the existing database in my server in a laravel project. I have changed the *.env* file however it is still not connecting to the host. I am not using homestead. Is this creating any problems.

db host name in .env file

> DB_HOST=db***.db.1and1.com

I see the below mentioned error when I try to write a query using the database

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does not show you any errors?

Comment: What errors do you see? You need to give us more information

Comment: I see this error:  php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: Betcha that domain only works on 1and1's internal DNS and isn't available externally. Contact their support if you're getting this from within one of their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your remote database and check the credentials. You might be missing something with that URL.

Comment: I have used the same host name to connect to the database in my php codes..but I can't understand  why I not able to connect through laravel